# laravel modal submit form getting error "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:"

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel, modal-dialog

I have a login form in a modal. which is in header.php file (header file is in views/include) that have been included to welcome.blade.php file. When I submit login form it gives this error "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:"

```
<a class="header-login-btn" href="#popup1">
Login&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

```
                    <ul class="ds-btn">
                    <li class="box-popop1">
                        <a class="header-login-btn" href="#popup1">
                            Login&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
                        <div class="popup">
                            <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                            <div class="account-box">
                                <div class="login-popup-header">
                                    Login
                                </div>
                                <form class="form-signin" action="loginUser" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required autofocus />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
                                    </div>
                                    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <label class="checkbox-01 checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" />
                                        Keep me signed in
                                    </label>
                                </form>
                                <div class="or-box row-block">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 row-block">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create New Account</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
```

this is my Route

```
Route::post("loginUser", 'Controller@loginUser');
```

this is the output I'm getting
[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

with just:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

The latter will inject the appropriate form input to satisfy the CSRF token.  Alternatively, try adding the following tag to your header and then passing it in the headers via your ajax call (as detailed in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)).

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: thank you. It worked. I had to rename header.php to header.blade.php also.